# How do I change one Directive when I click another Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, rxjs

So here's my problem:

I have a page which displays two different graphs. Each of these graphs are there own Directives which has their own isolate scope.

When a user clicks on one of the bar's in the chart in Directive #1, I need the graph in Directive #2 to change.

Currently both Chart Directives are being fed their respective data sets from the Controller of this page.

Now from what I've seen I really have about three options:

1. Pass a callback function into Directive #1 which be called when the chart is selected. This callback function will exist on the Controller of the page and then can change the necessary data in order to get Directive #2 to update via data-binding.
2. Events. Fire an event on $rootScope inside of Directive #1 when the chart is selected. I can then listen to this event on the Controller and change the data in Directive #2 to update it via data-binding.
3. Use a Library like Rx.JS in order to make an observable inside of Directive #1. I haven't used Rx.JS with Angular that much so to be honest I have no idea if this would even work or what it would look like. But if I could expose this Observable to page's Controller from within Directive #1 then I should be able to subscribe to it and update Directive #2 when necessary.

Now I have a good understanding of Solution #1 and #2 but they have their own issues:

1. This very quickly could turn into "callback hell" and doesn't seem to be a very "Angular" solution. This also creates a bit of a tight dependency between the page's Controller and this very generic Chart Directive. Out of my options  I think this is the best solution but I would love a better one.
2. I have to build a way to specify id's on the event names that are unique to that explicit instantiation of the directive, since theoretically there could be more than one of these Chart Directives on the page.

I would love to know if anyone has any other ideas that I haven't thought of or a better approach? Maybe even something that I'm not aware of that Rx.JS offers with Observable's?

TLDR: I need to click on Directive #1 and have it effect what is currently being displayed in Directive #2.

Comment: I don't see the shortcomings you are seeing with #1. There isn't a tight dependency between your generic chart directive because it takes a callback to call when it is clicked. This directive can be used anywhere and it's up to the controller to decide what the callback function should do. In addition, look into promises to avoid callback hell.

Comment: Alternatively, you could broadcast from the controller instead of firing an event on $rootScope. It seems to be bad practice to pollute $rootScope except for specific circumstances I don't entirely understand and someone more knowledgeable can fill in the details.

Comment: I've also heard of people using services for these types of cases, where the directive and controller will share a service.

Comment: @PDN A service interaction might be another possible solution. The issue that I have with that I guess is that the Service is very specific to this use case, it's a service specifically designed to interact with these two Directives. If there was a way that it was entirely generic though, then I think that could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by using two binding scopes in your directive like,

```
.directive('graphOne', function () {
   return {
       template: blah/blah.html,
       scope: {
         scopeToPass: '='
       }
   }
})

and 

.directive('graphTwo', function () {
   return {
       template: blah1/blah1.html,
       scope: {
         scopeToGet: '='
       }
   }
})
```

and in html

```
<graph-one scope-to-pass="uniqueScope"></graph-one>
<graph-two scope-to-get="uniqueScope"></graph-two>
```

Since we are assign $scope.uniqueScope to both directives, and the scopeToPass is two way binding, when the value of scopeToPass get changed it will be passed to uniqueScope and from uniqueScope it will be passed to scopeToGet.

Comment: Ahhh, so the problem with this solution is that it's assuming the two Directives are using the same data set. These graphs are entirely different data sets. But I also don't like this solution from the perspective that it creates a tight dependency directly between the two directives. In other words they both have to understand a shared model. Since these Graph Directives are entirely different graph types/directives, they should be independent from each other and not have to have knowledge of the others model.